# Regex for words and words beginning with a non-alphanumeric character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to highlight certain words/character sequences in HTML using the following JavaScript function:

```
function _highlight(input, keyword, colour) {
    var regex = "(\\b)(" + keyword + ")(\\b)";
    var r = new RegExp(regex, "g");
    return input.replace(r, "$1<span style=\"color: " + colour + ";\">$2</span>$3");
}
```

*`input` is the user-inputted text, `keyword` is the word to match and `colour` is the colour to highlight the keyword in.*

This works fine for most of the words in the mapping of words to highlighting colour. However, some words start with a special character, for example `&TEXT`. In these cases, the regex does not match.

I have tried using the following alternative regex with the given outcomes:

```
var regex = "(\.*[^0-9A-Za-z_]+)(" + keyword + ")([^0-9A-Za-z_]+\.*)";
```

matches all the words/character sequences as required but doesn't work at the beginning/end of strings because it needs a single character not matching the character class.

```
var regex = "(\\B)(" + keyword + ")(\\b)";
```

matches the words that begin with a special character but not the normal alphanumeric string.

How would I write a regex expression that matches these keywords when they are not immediately preceded or followed by alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Can you give some examples of some simple input text so that we don't have to guess. I'm thinking something like this should work: `"(\\b|[^0-9A-Za-z_]+)" + keyword + "(\\b)"`.

Comment: Try something like [`var regex = "(\\W|\\b|^)(" + keyword + ")(?!\\w)";`](https://tio.run/##TU9fS8MwEH/vpzjDsAnWiT6J3ebTvoAM9CEoWXbLuoUkXNN2w/nZa9Mh8@Dgd/D7d3vVqlpTFeJ9@9z328bpWHkHX7vK7OywkVcuNLGAA546T5sCtLe@IQHfGQzTKgJCg0eYA@NSvp@lXJ8/BWdw96cZEBP89UbKTrDyKhskDjt4Q7M8Bj66FMAMExcOYWzIwZg/JQxWaeQ0MCaPszooB3U8WZxLlhrRC6TES7kUWEq2mDzNHhJzkSx/skx7V3uLU@sN//dhvvX@drX8WMFaUV5APh4JEG5yIcq@/wU) (remove the `$3` in replacement)

Comment: Please provide comprehensive examples of `input` and `keyword`